# Do I ever stop getting review tests?

Tags: discussion, reviewing

I recently made it over 1k rep and unlocked all types of reviews, so I've been doing a bit of reviewing. At any given time there are maybe 3 or 4 reviews to do max, but almost every time I do any more than 1 at a time, I get a test review.

For those of you that don't know, this is when it will give me a review that should clearly prompt a certain response. An example is a *Reopen Vote* review on a question that should clearly stay closed, like "What's black and white and red all over?" Obviously this question would be closed as too broad and that is what you are supposed to answer in the review queue.

My question is if I will ever stop getting these? Or maybe stop getting them so frequently? They are just a little bit annoying. Whenever I'm reviewing, I've already seen all the new puzzles posted, and probably have one open in another tab. It ends up being pretty obvious that I'm being faced with a test when it says "answered 1 hour ago" but I haven't seen the question yet.

*Side note:* My guess is that it gives out tests once or twice per time you review, so if there were more reviews at once, I'd see them less frequently compared to non-tests.

Comment: FYI, I've done more reviews than anyone else and still get the occasional review audit, including in categories such as 'Close Votes' where I've _already_ passed review audits.

Answer (score 3):

Looking through your complete review history, it looks like you've only had one audit so far.

There are no published details on how the review audit system works, but I've found through experience that the more audits I pass, the less I get audited. (Even mods get regular audits.)

Just give the system time to learn your reviewing habits a bit better, and the audits should mostly subside on their own.

Comment: That's weird that it says only one, because I'm positive I've had at least two, and I think it's been three.

Comment: @MisterEman I'll check again in a bit. I'm far from error-prone.

Comment: @MisterEman Yeah, checked again; only one review audit of eleven total reviews.